# Dual count query with join

Tags: mysql

I have four tables and I need to get 2 counts and then group them by a users table.

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM  user_share us
        INNER JOIN user_share_recipient usr
        ON usr.share_id = us.id
        WHERE usr.sent_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
    ) AS Shares,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   resource_tracking
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
    ) AS Views

FROM    dual
```

That works to get the total counts from the three tables, but I need to join a fourth users table and then group each of them by username. So i can

```
select first name, last name (then the shares count)(then the views count) 
from users (join the tables above on user_id columns on both tables)
 group by username
```

so that I end up with a result like:

```
First Name    Last Name     Shares    Views

  John         Smith         20        40
```

Is this even possible? I can't use temporary tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       COALESCE(Shares.s_count,0), 
       COALESCE(VIEWS.v_count,0)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT us.user_id, COUNT(*) AS s_count
  FROM user_share us
  INNER JOIN user_share_recipient usr ON usr.share_id = us.id
  WHERE usr.sent_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
  GROUP BY us.user_id
  ) AS Shares ON u.user_id = Shares.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS v_count
  FROM resource_tracking
  WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS VIEWS ON u.user_id = VIEWS.user_id
```

Used LEFT JOIN to get results even when there is no shares or views. And used COALESCE TO put them as 0 in those cases.

Comment: Very nice Sir, Very nice indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, instead of "from dual", use "from users". Then, on the inner sub-selects, add a clause that only selects the count for the particular user. Something like this:

```
SELECT  username, max(FIRST_NAME), max(LAST_NAME),
   (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM  user_share us
        INNER JOIN user_share_recipient usr
        ON usr.share_id = us.id
        WHERE usr.sent_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
          and users.USER_ID = us.user_id
    ) AS Shares,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   resource_tracking
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
     and users.USER_ID = resource_tracking.user_id
    ) AS Views

FROM  users
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT um.firstname, um.lastname, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM user_share AS us
    INNER JOIN user_share_recipient AS usr
    ON usr.share_id = us.id
  WHERE usr.sent_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
    AND um.user_id = us.user_id
) AS Shares,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM resource_tracking AS rt
  WHERE rt.created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-31'
    AND um.user_id = rt.user_id
) AS Views,
FROM users AS um
```